How to get a competition invite on Real Racing3
I've been sending invites to my friend but he's not getting them, we've been trying for some time now still he doesn't get it. Please, tell me if there's something I'm forgetting to do. I'd appreciate help.

Hi Luyanda, an invite how? Through the game? And can you please use punctuation to make your question read easier?
